# MRPT library COpenGLScenePtr does not name a type

Tags: c++, mobile-robot-toolkit

I have installed `mrpt` from [here](https://www.mrpt.org/MRPT_in_GNU/Linux_repositories) for running [this](https://github.com/MarianoJT88/PD-Flow) project. The problem is that I keep getting the following error.

```
error: ‘COpenGLScenePtr’ in namespace ‘mrpt::opengl’ does not name a type
     opengl::COpenGLScenePtr  scene;
```

in the `scene_flow_visualization.h` file of the project.

I also verified that there's a header file called `COpenGLScenePtr.h` which I manually tried to add inside `scene_flow_visualization.h`, but that still doesn't work.

What could be the issue ? Does anybody help me get rid of this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PD-Flow` was designed for the MRPT 1.5.* series. Your problem is due to the [change of smart pointer types](http://mrpt.ual.es/reference/master/porting_mrpt2.html) from `FooPtr` to `Foo::Ptr` in the MRPT 2.* series, which you have installed.

Please, remove your MRPT packages:

```
sudo apt remove libmrpt* mrpt*
```

remove the mrpt-2 PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:joseluisblancoc/mrpt
```

and re-add them from this alternative PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joseluisblancoc/mrpt-1.5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmrpt-dev mrpt-apps
```

If even after this you got problems, open an issue ticket to the PD-Flow repository.